# How to calculate the value of load capacitor for designing an op amp for pipeline ADC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, integrated-circuit

I'm working on 12-bit 200 MS/s pipeline ADC design. this ADC has 5 stage. the structure of ADC is 2.5-2.5-2.5-2.5-4 bit. In the first step I want to design a fully differential folded cascode op amp for my first 2.5-bit stage and can not find any reference to calculate the load capacitor for op amp. This capacitor must show the load of next stage on designing op amp.
this figure show my ADC structure:

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific, like define the ADC and provide a link. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask This is a Q&A forum for professionals. A professional question will get a professional answer. Properly punctuate your questions. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I asked the question from Proffessor Razavi and he answered as:

"The minimum value of the capacitors in an MDAC is determined by matching or kT/C noise. The mismatch translates to gain error, which is difficult to calibrate.
If mismatch is not the bottleneck, then kT/C noise is the determining factor. I
doubt the capacitor values will be too small for a 12-bit ADC with a reasonable
LSB size, e.g., 0.25 mV. You need to make sure kT/C is well below LSB^2 / 12."

Comment: This isn't an answer. It is information that belongs in the question.